# Install numpy on Snow Leopard

Tags: python, numpy, version, osx-snow-leopard, gcc-4.2

When I try to install numpy over a python.org python2.6 installation, I get these errors on my OS X terminal.

```
sh: gcc-4.2: command not found
```

And this causes failure. I noticed a pastebin (http://pastebin.com/hieSKe3A) already on this issue but I'm unable to find an answer online that works for Snow Leopard (there seem to be a lot of answers for Lion).

I noticed numpy requires the python.org python2.6 installation. I'm trying to do that. Btw, if there is a way for me to prevent the installer of the numpy mpkg from checking the python version available? (If yes, I may have another hacky way to do this.)

Help?

Thanks.

Comment: Just stressing on `Snow Leopard` here. There isn't a version I can install on Snow Leopard.

Comment: Yes. But I just need the command line tools, right? I have Xcode 4 that I bought and then, had trouble re-installing (becoz they changed the Xcode installation procedure a lot) when I reset my laptop. Just want to be sure I don't kill my current Xcode install for nothing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have two main options to install gcc 4.2 on Snow Leopard:

1. Download pre-built binaries from [**osx-gcc-installer**](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/downloads). This is the simplest way.
2. Download the **Command Line Tools for Xcode** package in the [Developer Center](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) and follow [this guide](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45651/xcode-4-and-snow-leopard/45660#answer-45660) to make it install on Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal type “gcc“, you will get message “command not found”.

C or GCC compiler is needed some times and MAC OS X does not have this installed by default

to install gcc compiler you will need to download and install command line tools for xcode (see Apples developer page)

Comment: Look at my comment above. I know all this. I've googled like crazy. `Snow Leopard` is my problem.

Comment: GCC installer for snowleopard 
https://github.com/downloads/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/GCC-10.6.pkg